# dask kubernetes import local library

Tags: python, kubernetes, dask, dask-kubernetes

When working on a local project, `from local_project.funcs import local_func` will fail in the cluster because `local_project` is not installed.

This forces me to develop everything on the same file.

Solutions? Is there a way to "import" the contents of the module into the working file so that the cluster doesn't need to import it?

Installing the `local_project` in the cluster is not development friendly because any change in an imported feature requires a cluster redeploy.

```py
import dask
from dask_kubernetes import KubeCluster, make_pod_spec
from local_project.funcs import local_func

pod_spec = make_pod_spec(
    image="daskdev/dask:latest",
    memory_limit="4G",
    memory_request="4G",
    cpu_limit=1,
    cpu_request=1,
)
cluster = KubeCluster(pod_spec)

df = dask.datasets.timeseries()
df.groupby('id').apply(local_func)  #fails if local_project not installed in cluster
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the solution to this is to make your own docker image.  If you have only a single file, or an egg or zip file then you might also look into the `Client.upload_file` method

Comment: to automate in code I did: `_ = subprocess.check_call(["python", "setup.py", "bdist_egg"])` and then `client.upload_file(glob.glob("./dist/*.egg")[0])`